# What is wrong with this circle-to-circle collision?

Tags: java, physics, collision

I have a simple java application that tests for collision off 4 walls and off each of the 10 balls... I have the walls figured out but circle-to-circle doesn't seem to work for me. When I run this segment along with the rest of the program I get 10 very shaky circles (that appear to be colliding with themselves) and they don't move very much at all. If I take this segment out I get 10 circles that move smoothly and collide off of the 4 walls. Can someone tell me what might be causing the problem? THANKS

```
for (int j = 0; j < ballnum; ++j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < ballnum; ++k) {
        if (Math.sqrt((Math.pow(balls[j].givebackpoint().x - balls[k].givebackpoint().x, 2))
            + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(balls[j].givebackpoint().y - balls[k].givebackpoint().y, 2)))) <= 2 * RADIUS) {
            if (balls[j].givebackangle() >= 180) {
                balls[j].setangle(balls[j].givebackangle()-180);
                                        }
            else{
                balls[j].setangle(360-balls[j].givebackangle());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking each ball against itself.

You need to skip running the tests when j == k with a line like this at the top of your inner for loop:

```
if (j == k)
    continue;
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to fix it. I understand what you are saying though. I will continue to play around with it and post back later...

Comment: Are you certain that your angle-modification code is correct? I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure... It seemed like it would work to me. But how would you go about doing it? Just curious

Comment: It works now. I took out the separate Math.sqrt and made just one at the beginning of the statement. It's still hairy but I think I can work with it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing it, you don't seem to be skipping where `j == k`.  So you are right that they are colliding with themselves.